# ssl not working with nginx + uwsgi + django

Tags: django, nginx, uwsgi

hi i'm coding my own server with django ,nginx, and uwsgi
the problem is when i access https://localhost , ssl work.
but https://domainname , it wont work.
what is wrong in my code?

nginx.conf

```
worker_processes  1;
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;


    keepalive_timeout  65;
upstream django {
        #server 172.30.1.40:8000;
        server localhost:8000;
}
    server {
        server_name  fidochallenge486.tk;
        listen 8080;
        location / {
                uwsgi_pass django;
                include /usr/local/etc/nginx/uwsgi_params;
                proxy_redirect off;
                proxy_pass_header Server;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000/;
                proxy_redirect off;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
        }
}
  server {
        listen       443 ssl;
        server_name  fidochallenge486.tk;

        ssl_certificate      /Users/junbeomkwak/Downloads/fidochallenge486.tk/bundle.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key  /Users/junbeomkwak/Downloads/fidochallenge486.tk/privkey.key;
        #ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
        #ssl_session_timeout  5m;

        #ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
        #ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;

        location / {
                include /usr/local/etc/nginx/uwsgi_params;
                uwsgi_pass django;
        }
    }
}
```

fido_project.conf

```
upstream django {
        server 172.30.1.40:8000;
}
server {
        listen 8080;
        server_name domainname;
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        location / {
                uwsgi_pass django;
                proxy_pass 172.30.1.40:8000;
        }

}
server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name domainname;
        if ($host = domainname') {
                return 301 https://domainname$request_uri;
        }
        ssl_certificate /Users/junbeomkwak/Downloads/fidochallenge486.tk/bundle.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /Users/junbeomkwak/Downloads/fidochallenge486.tk/privkey.pem;
        ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
        ssl_session_timeout  5m;

        ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;
        location / {
                uwsgi_pass django;
                include /usr/local/etc/nginx/uwsgi_params;
                #proxy_pass 172.30.1.40:8000; // local
        }
}
```

edited by 10:55 kst
i edited what you said.. not working
need some file? like ini file or something..

Comment: you should say this problem to your host company

Answer (score 0):

Here are some strange parts of your config:

```
server {
        listen 8080;
        server_name domainname;
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        location / {
                uwsgi_pass django;
                proxy_pass 172.30.1.40:8000;
        }

}
```

This redirect

```
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
```

is usually used for HTTP to HTTPS redirection when end user types `domainname` in his browser address bar without specifying an `https://` prefix. Having that in a `server` block that listen on port 8080 is quite strange because end user had to type `domainname:8080` to get redirected to `https://domainname`. Usually this type of redirect is used in a `server` block that listen on a default HTTP port 80. Anyway

```
        location / {
                uwsgi_pass django;
                proxy_pass 172.30.1.40:8000;
        }
```

had no sense here because it would never executed. Additionally, you should have only `proxy_pass` or `uwsgi_pass`, not both.

Next one:

```
server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name domainname;
        if ($host = domainname') {
                return 301 https://domainname$request_uri;
        }
        ...
```

What is that `if` block for? It would give you endless redirection from HTTPS to HTTPS which definitely has no sense at all. Looks like you copy-pasted it from some other config without understanding what does it mean. Remove it.

Comment: I looked closer at your `nginx.conf`, looks like you copy-pasted it with errors (for example, I think `"nginx.conf" 66L, 1729C` line isn't from that config file). Can you fix it?

Comment: Edit your question, do not paste `nginx.conf` in the comments.